# Python Requests Proxy

Tags: python, http, proxy, request

I am trying to use the python requests module and pass a proxy through as so through the `host:port` that I assign it...

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://host:port'}
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

This worked for me literally 3 days ago. I then moved on to something else within my project and came back to it not working. I am getting an error saying that I am missing dependencies for SOCKS support as follows...

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: Missing dependencies for SOCKS support.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that you don't have OS environement variable for proxy set ?

You can check it with `env | grep proxy`.